# Confusion matrix perfect result. Can it be true?

Tags: validation, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm studying ML. And I want to check quality of my model.

Here some sample code:

```
log_reg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000, solver='liblinear', C=1)
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
confusion_matrix(y_test, log_reg.predict(X_test))
```

And I got:

```
array([[ 979,    0],
       [   0, 1052]], dtype=int64)
```

So this means that this model is perfect? Maybe I do some mistakes. I don't think that 100% TN and TF values is good, because it's too good to be true.

Answer (score 1):

If it is too good to be true, it probably is. Check for information leak into your test dataset. Information about the test set could leak into training due to multiple reasons. Have a read at google and understand the sources. One common source is due to normalisation. If you did normalise/standardise the train and test data together, you are passing the information of mean and standard deviation of training data to test data. Also, please make sure your test dataset is not randomly shuffled in case if you are using time-series data. Timeseries dataset has autocorrelation, the previous timepoint has information about the next time point. If you pass the t-1 data point to train and t datapoint to test, it would perform very well.
Having said this, there is also a good possibility that if there exists a hyperplane that perfectly separates your dataset, you could get results like that. Most of the toy datasets can be perfectly separated using sophisticated techniques. Hopefully, I helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't worry, everyone has faced this issue. Results like these make you get up and share them with everyone. Unfortunately, almost every time, it is highly likely that there is something wrong.
2. I think there has been an "information leakage", which means the input data contains some feature/s that is/are being used instead of all the features. In this case, models do not generalize. However, I think it is pretty easy to determine when there is been an information leakage.

For example, one of the ways to check, if you suspect there has been an "information leakage", is to look at the feature importance plot. If only one or two features have very huge importance compared to the other features, then it is highly likely that something is wrong with your input data or modeling approach.

Comment: I did exactly the same as described in this article. Same dataset, same operations and same result. https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-perfect-mushroom-classifier-ceb9d99ae87e

Comment: @VladTimofeev 

I analyzed the tutorial. There are 2 points I would like to explain. 1) In the tutorial, the author included the target variable in the training data X_train & X_test. (This is a mistake.) 2) Even if we fix this, the accuracy is still high. Why? The reason is due to 2 features: a) odor b) spore-print-color.

Comment: If we use one-hot encoded version of these 2 columns, we can actually predict mushrooms with almost similar accuracy compared to using all features. So this means that in this toy example, these 2 features are great predictors whether a mushroom is poisonous or edible. I believe these two features are also used in real life to distinguish mushrooms.

Comment: This means, that yes! in this tutorial it is possible to achieve a perfect accuracy. However, as a friendly suggestion, I would say that it is highly unlikely that you will get perfect predictions in real-life datasets.